# Loop through list and hide blanks

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a list called "District List" on one tab and a Template that is driven by putting the name of a district into Cell C3.  Each District has a wildly varying number of branches (between 1 & 500+ branches depending on the District) so the report template has a lot of blank space in some cases.  I came up with this to loop through the District List, copy the Template tab, rename it the District Name, insert the name of the district into Cell C3, and then I have another loop to hide the blank rows.

It works, but it takes forever, like 5 minutes per tab, then after about four tabs, I get an object error at the first like of Sub CreateTabsFromList.

Is there a problem with the code, or is this just a really inefficient way to do this?  If so can anyone help with a better method?

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("a1:a1000") 'Sets range well beyond the last possible row with data
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True  'Hide the row if the cell in A is blank
Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("District List").Range("A1")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
   Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Range("C3").Value = MyCell.Value 'Pastes value in C3
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames worksheet
    HideRows 'Hides rows where cell in column A is ""


Next MyCell
```

End Sub

Comment: You never mark any answer? Did you never get a valid answer to your question or you just dont know how to do it?

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking about one of my older posts, I went back just now and marked an answer.  For this one I just posted a few minutes ago, have not gotten an answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting/Hiding  rows, 1 by 1 is the slowest method. Always club them in one range and delete/hide them in one go, also looping through cells is slower than looping array.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim lCtr    As Long
    Dim rngDel  As Range
    Dim r       As Range
    Dim arr

    Set r = Range("a1:a1000") 'Sets range well beyond the last possible row with data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    arr = r
    For lCtr = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(lCtr, 1) = "" Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = Cells(lCtr, 1) 'harcoded 1 as you are using column A
             Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, Cells(lCtr, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next


    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        rngDel.EntireRow.Hidden=True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

takes fraction of a second for 1000 rows.